# Sklearn feature selection

Tags: python, scikit-learn, classification, feature-selection

I have been unable to use any of the Sklearn feature extraction methods without getting the following error:

"TypeError: cannot perform reduce with flexible type"

Working from examples, the feature extraction methods appear to only work for non-classification problems.  I am of course, trying to do a classification problem.  How can I fix this?

Example code:

```
from sklearn.feature_selection import RFE
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
from sklearn.datasets import load_boston
import random

# Load data
boston = load_boston()
X = boston["data"]
Y = boston["target"]

# Make a classification problem
classes = ['a', 'b', 'c']
Y = [random.choice(classes) for entry in Y]

# Perform feature selection
names = boston["feature_names"]
lr = LinearRegression()
rfe = RFE(lr, n_features_to_select=1)
rfe.fit(X, Y)

print "Features sorted by their rank:"
print sorted(zip(map(lambda x: round(x, 4), rfe.ranking_), names))
```

Comment: where is your load_boston() method?

Comment: Approaching a classification problem through linear regression may not be the right way to go. http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/22381/why-not-approach-classification-through-regression

Answer (score 1):

I guess the following will solve your problem.

```
X = np.array(X, dtype = 'float_')
Y = np.array(X, dtype = 'float_')
```

Do it before calling the `fit` method. You can also use `int_` instead of `float_`. It totally depends on the data type you need.

If your labels are `string`, then you can use [LabelEncoder](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.LabelEncoder.html) to encode the labels into integers.

```
from sklearn import preprocessing    
le = preprocessing.LabelEncoder()
le = le.fit_transform(Y)
model.fit(X, le)
```

Comment: Won't encoding labels to integers cause problems?  The feature selection method might understand class 2 to be "less" than class 3, while in reality, this relationship doesn't exist.

Comment: No, this shouldn't create any problem. Labels are just label, it shouldn't matter for classification task. You can also get the mapping between your string labels and converted integer label.